# Vuetify how to add CSS class to HTML <input>

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js, yandex-metrika

I have a `<v-text-field>` which collects user e-mail address and I need to add `ym-record-keys` CSS class to **`<input>`** element according to [Yandex Metrica guideline](https://yandex.com/support/metrica/webvisor-v2/settings.html#record-field). So I tried to add it like this but it adds class to the parent div. How can I add `ym-record-keys` class to HTML input element?

```html
<v-text-field
  v-model="item.customer.mail"
  type="email"
  :rules="emailRules"
  hide-details="auto"
  class="ym-record-keys"
  solo 
>
</v-text-field>
```

[image: html output]

I need to achieve this output:

```html
<input id="input-1055" type="email" class="ym-record-keys">
```

Comment: You can do only with jquery or js. Vuetify doesn't have such option yet.

Comment: @FatimaMazhit any idea how can I do this with JavaScript in Vue?

Comment: `document.querySelector("div.ym-record-keys input[type='email']").classList.add("ym-record-keys");` Smth like that

Comment: I works but it wasn't the solution I hope to find. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I know i hope vuetify devs will add that feature.

Answer (score 1):

I needed this ability as well because another plugin I was using expects a certain class to exist on my input elements.

In order to achieve this I created a simple wrapper around Vuetify's [**`v-text-field`**](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-text-field/) that adds the ability to pass in a `class` to the `input` element:

Create a `TextInput.vue` component:

```
<script>
import { VTextField } from 'vuetify/lib';

export default {
  name: 'text-input',
  extends: VTextField,
  props: {
    inputClass: {
      note: 'A class that gets applied to the input',
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    // Applying the `class` to the input
    // element below if it has values
    const inputEl = this.$el.querySelector('input');

    if (this.inputClass) {
      inputEl.classList.add(this.inputClass);
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

Then used like this:

```
<text-input v-model="myModel" input-class="my-css-class" />
```

Which results in your input looking like this:

```
<input id="idGeneratedFromVuetify" type="text" class="my-css-class">
```

You can modify this to fit any other attributes you may want, or you could make it more dynamic if your use case needs that by using the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) with props.

Answer (score -1):

You can try the following to bind the class

```
:class=["ym-record-keys"]
```

or

```
:class="'ym-record-keys'"
```

Comment: Both did not work. I am getting the same output. @tipu dany